# Provide compiler with a proof without pattern matching

Tags: haskell, dependent-type

Let's say I have a proof:

```
-- (pseudocode) m and n are natural numbers
proof :: forall m n. (1 <= m, m < n) => SNat n -> SNat m -> (1 <= n - 1)
proof _ _ = unsafeCoerce Refl
```

If I were to use it elsewhere in my code I would have to pattern match on `proof` like so:

```
...
case proof n m of
  Refl -> ...
...
```

But `proof` holds for any `n` and `m` so unnecessary pattern matching that always matches is done during runtime. How to avoid this ?

**EDIT** Use case:

```
--                  0 1 2 3 4 ... n-1
--returns Vec n a : 1 0 0 0 0 ... 0
helper :: (UVec a, Num a) => SNat n -> Vec n a
helper n = case isZero n of
  NonZero -> 1 `vcons` vpreplicate (sPred n) 0
  Zero -> vnil

proof1 :: forall n m . (CmpNat n m ~ GT) => SNat n -> SNat m -> ((CmpNat (n :- 1) (m :- 1)) :~: GT)
proof1 n m = unsafeCoerce Refl

proof2 :: forall n m . (1 <= m, (CmpNat n m) ~ GT) => SNat n -> SNat m -> ((1 <=? (n :- 1)) :~: True)
proof2 n m = unsafeCoerce Refl

--                  0 1 2 ... m . . . . . . n-1
--returns Vec n a : 0 0 0 ... 1 0 0 0 0 ... 0
helper2 :: forall a m n.(UVec a, Num a, 1 <= n, (CmpNat n m) ~ GT) => SNat n -> SNat m -> Vec n a
helper2 size m = case (isZero m, proof1 size m) of
  (NonZero, Refl) ->
    case (proof2 size m) of
      Refl -> (0 :: a) `vcons` helper2 (sPred size) (sPred m)

  (Zero,_) -> helper size
```

If `helper2` is assumed to be used very often extra pattern matching adds overhead.

Comment: Please show a full use case and what bothers you about it.

Comment: If the proof is inlined, the compiler might be able to optimize it away. Anyway, it's a O(1) match, so even without optimization it does not cost a lot. (Be careful, though, since by coercing your proofs you can easily violate type safety.)

Comment: I think the standard trick for optimizing proofs is to actually do the proof (so don't have `unsafeCoerce Refl` as the body of the `proof`), but then add a rewrite `RULE` to optimize `proof x y` into `unsafeCoerce Refl`. That way, you can "run" your proofs when your code is compiled without optimizations, and not run them when your code is compiled with optimizations.

Comment: Reference (at least, this is where I first heard about it) for @Alec's suggestion: https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2016/07/24/dependent-types-in-haskell-progress-report/

Comment: What are the imports / definitions your code relies upon? Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As for "free" coercions, look into introducing [type classes whose sole purpose is to add equality constraints](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GgD0KUxMaQs#t=40m)